# Erro ao usar função imagejpeg em função interna de classe PHP

Tags: php

Fiz uma classe para gerar thumbs de imagens:

```
class Thumbnail {

private static $allowedTypes = [IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_BMP];
private $JPEGQuality = 75;

public function makeTumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {
    $aImage = $this->imageCreateFromAny($src);

    if (!$aImage) {
        return false;
    }

    $source_image = $aImage['image'];
    $type = $aImage['type'];
    $width  = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);
    // usando assim funciona
    // imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
    // usando em uma funçao o imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest); salva o arquivo, mas quando tento abrir diz que não é um .jpeg válido
    $this->imageSave($virtual_image, $dest, $type);

    return true;
}

private function imageSave($virtual_image, $dest, $type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF :
            imagegif($virtual_image, $dest);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
            imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG :
            imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_BMP :
            imagewbmp($virtual_image, $dest);
            break;
    }
}

private function imageCreateFromAny($src) {
    $type = exif_imagetype($src);
    if (!in_array($type, self::$allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF :
            $rImage = imageCreateFromGif($src);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
            $rImage = imageCreateFromJpeg($src);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG :
            $rImage = imageCreateFromPng($src);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_BMP :
            $rImage = imageCreateFromBmp($src);
            break;
    }
    return ['image' => $rImage, 'type' => $type];
  }
}

$oThumb = new Thumbnail();

$src = __DIR__.'/imagem_1.jpg';
$dest = __DIR__.'/thumb/thumb_imagem_1.jpg';
$desired_width = 256;
$oThumb->makeTumb($src, $dest, $desired_width);
```

Mas salva a imagem e quando tento abrir diz que não é um arquivo de imagem  válido, a não ser que use função `imagejpeg` de forma direta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Aqui de essa mensagem da imagem :(

Comment: A pasta thumb tem permissão de escrita e execução?

Comment: Sim, tá com 777

Comment: Renomeia o thumb com a extensão .txt e tenta abrir em um editor de texto, caso sejam dados "binários" volte aqui no site e me informa a versão do PHP que esta usando.

Comment: sim, estou usando PHP 7.

Comment: Apaga a thumb e tenta gerar novamente.

Comment: Tem como me enviar o `imagem_1.jpg`?

Comment: no navegador a imagem abre normal, mas no gerenciador de arquivos dá erro.

Comment: Deve ser o gerenciador que não esta no mesmo grupo do usuário do Apache, faz o seguinte, depois de gravar a imagem execute `$oThumb->makeTumb($src, $dest, $desired_width); chmod($dest, 0777);` e tente abrir novamente no gerenciador.

Comment: :(, mesma coisa, vou testar em outro pc para ver.